# There is a way to create a fixed-stroke path while zooming in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to draw a `Path` in a `SurfaceView` through a `Bitmap`

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.draw(canvas);
   mCanvas.drawPath(mPath);
   canvas.setMatrix(mMatrix);
   canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap);
}
```

I have to use a `Bitmap` because I need to save drawings. The `SurfaceView` has a `OnScaleListener` through which I can zoom. There is a simple way to keep the path's stroke fixed while zooming? The zoom must affect only the scale of the path (points coordinates) but not the stroke... Any idea?

Comment: see Path#transform

Comment: If you want to override `draw()` or `onDraw()` you should use a custom View (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) rather than a SurfaceView. Otherwise you're potentially drawing everything twice.